# How to include new files in SnailSVN commit

Tags: macos, svn

In my project I created new files after update local copy with subversion, by these new files are not under version control, and a don't know how to include them in my commit. 
[image: Finder with files that are under version control and files that are not]

I tried to check "Show unversioned files" on the commit dialog but it show only a small portion of my new files.

[image: Commit dialog with "Show unversioned files" checked]